# Salesforce Environment hub - is it for use on client orgs?

Tags: org

I have just got the Environment hub working (ISV Partner). Seems to be pretty slick and very easy to tie up all my development environments to.

Now, is it intended that I use it to log into clients' orgs?

Jus' wonderin'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. An org is allowed to have a single Parent Environment Id only. Client orgs are not ours to associate and one will preclude them from using their own environment hub by attempting this.

As an ISV partner, the normal mechanism for administering client orgs is the License Management App. Clients explicitly Grant Login Access and a special link will appear in the Subscribers tab.

Comment: Many thanks for that. I am just venturing from supporting/consulting/implementing Salesforce to offering a software package, so that is really useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My concern about using for client orgs was that it stores YOUR org ID in their org. I wondered if revealing org ID was an issue... then I noticed that part of your org ID is used in tracking cases (sufficient that you can re-construct the whole org ID).

My concern was that the org ID allows for injection of information into an org (through the web-to-lead functionality). However, as the org ID is regularly exposed through other means, I have concluded that it is safe to use the environment hub with client orgs.

Correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: Using Environment Hub with client orgs is highly inadvisable. Do not recommend.